# Onclick div as link event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i know this question has been made before, the problem is the solutions are not working for me. So i want to ask

If i have several divs like this, the id is what it change from one to other

```
 <div class="compareOuter" id="dv_111" onclick="location.href='index.php?page=item/view/111';"> 
Some checboxes
</div>
```

I have tried applying this solution , but i have something wrong cause its not working..

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

What im trying to is to clic in the checkboxes inside the div with onclick without this taking me to the url of the div,  just check the checkbox..

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have some divs for "items" wich are working great using onclick, the problem is those have some Checkboxes inside.. when i clic the checkbox, i am redirected to page, but i jus want to check the checkbox, inside that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then stop event propagation from the check boxes

```
$("div input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: awesome, i just added $(window).bind("load", function() cause the checkboxes are generated during the loading XD , its working! thanks